# jQuery DataTable rows conditional formatting, grand total by column

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have two tasks to do in DataTables:

> 1. To display green row if 'amount' field value is less than 500 and red if amount is more than 5000
> 2. To display sum by 'amount' column at the bottom

I am getting output if I call each function individually, but if I tried to call them together, I get no result.

```
   var table=$('table.display').DataTable(
    {"fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, 
    iDisplayIndexFull )
    {
       if (aData[5]<500){
       $('td', nRow).css('background-color', 'Orange');}
       else if (aData[5]>5000){$('td', nRow).css('background-color', '#9EF395');}}
    "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
        var api = this.api(), data;
        var intVal = function ( i ) {
            return typeof i === 'string' ?
                i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '')*1 :
                typeof i === 'number' ?
                    i : 0;};
        total = api
            .column(2)
            .data()
            .reduce( function (a, b) {
                return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
            }, 0 );
        pageTotal = api
            .column( 2, { page: 'current'} )
            .data()
            .reduce( function (a, b) {
                return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
            }, 0 );
        $( api.column( 2 ).footer() ).html(''+pageTotal +' ( '+ 
        total +' total)');}});} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```js
//source data
var myData = [
 {item: 'apple', amount: 250},
  {item: 'pear', amount: 570},
  {item: 'pinaple', amount: 6700},
  {item: 'banana', amount: 140}
];
//data table initialization
var dataTable = $('#mytable').DataTable({
 sDom: 't',
  data: myData,
  columns: [
   {data: 'item', title: 'item'},
    {data: 'amount', title: 'amount'}
  ]
});
//append sum
$('#mytable').append(`<tfoot>${Array(dataTable.columns().count()).fill('<th></th>').join('')}</tfoot>`);
var sum = dataTable.column(1).data().reduce((acc, entry) => acc+=entry);
$('#mytable tfoot th').eq(1).text(sum);
//conditional formatting
dataTable.rows().every(function(){
 let color = this.data().amount > 5000 ? 'red' : this.data().amount < 500 ? 'green' : 'unset';
  $(this.node()).css('background-color', color);
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <table id="mytable"></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this example :

```
 const Table = $('#foo').DataTable({
 . . . . . .,
 . . . . . .,
 drawCallback: function(){
   Table.columns(5, {
     page: 'current'
   }).every(function() {
     var sum = this
     .data()
     .reduce(function(a, b) {
        var x = parseFloat(a) || 0;
        var y = parseFloat(b) || 0;
        return x + y;
     }, 0);
     console.log(sum);
   $(this.footer()).html(sum);
   });
  }
});
```

in this case, the column was column number 5